# Grab Search Parameters from Ransack Gem Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ransack

I am using Ransack Search Gem for Rails3. Is there a way to grab the search parameters that the user typed into the search box?

I'd like to make it available in my view if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out:

categories_controller

```
def index
@q = Category.search(params[:q])
@categories = @q.result(:distinct => true)
end
```

view/_form.html.erb

```
%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
<% end %>

<%= @q.name_cont %>
```

The part I was missing was **@q.name_cont**. This outputs the string entered into the search form.